# Problem with StatusReport trait in Smart Home Actions

Tags: google-smart-home

I have a Security System with traits ***action.devices.traits.ArmDisarm*** and ***action.devices.traits.StatusReport*** and some other sensors: *WaterLeak Sensor*, *Door Sensor ...*

I report some errors about other devices with ***StatusReport*** state.
For example: when the door sensor detects that the door is open, the security system must give `deviceOpen` error.

When I say, *"Is my security system ok?"*, my server's response to the **query intent** is the JSON below, but Google Assistant says that he couldn't reach my action (*Unexpected error happened*).

Is there anything wrong with this response?

```
{
  "requestId": "10417064006786362499",
  "payload": {
    "devices": {
      "3rL3QL7Kq2HrQjs53Y7o": {
        "isArmed": true,
        "currentStatusReport": [
          {
            "blocking": true,
            "deviceTarget": "4BCIpzBWpgLA24mMI7r2",
            "priority": 0,
            "statusCode": "deviceOpen"
          },
          {
            "blocking": true,
            "deviceTarget": "MxRCd6ERRSWzYzyNTE8S",
            "priority": 0,
            "statusCode": "waterLeakDetected"
          }
        ],
        "status": "EXCEPTIONS",
        "online": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In Firebase Console there are no errors.

[Logs in Firebase Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UQVh.png)

Comment: Are you able to view any errors in your server logs or Stackdriver logs for Assistant Action?

Comment: In https://console.cloud.google.com, under Log Viewer there are no errors.

Comment: Is that for the "Assistant" category?

Comment: Logging resource is selected as "Google Assistant Action".

Comment: were you able to fix this? I'm having a lot of isseus with this trait, seems to be it is not ready yet

Comment: Hi, all the traits are ready and available to use. If you still face any issues regarding the same, then please create a request on our [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=655104&template=1284148).

Answer (score 0):

Your response to the query intent looks right, but there might be an error in other parts of the process. You can follow the [Troubleshooting Guide](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/troubleshooting) to see how your failed intent is counted in the Smart Home metrics and what are the details on your logs. (Firebase logs only gives info about your server. The logging mentioned in the guide (Google Cloud Logging) is a different and more comprehensive for the intent handling)